# Скачивание таблицы созданной через exceljs с сервера на express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

На бэке есть массив с объектами для заполнения таблицы эксель, при нажатии кнопки (на фронте) должна создастся таблица и выгрузиться в браузер.

Раньше таблица выгружалась без использования бэка с использованием file-saver:

```
return workbook.xlsx
    .writeBuffer()
    .then((buffer) =>
      FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([buffer]), `${Date.now()}_Базовая таблица.xlsx`)
    )
    .catch((err) => console.log('Error writing excel export', err));
```

Сейчас добавлен бэкенд на экспрессе, поскольку у меня мало опыта, я не могу понять как выгружать созданный файл минуя запись на диск.

Запрос с фронта:

```
class Api {
  constructor({ baseUrl, headers }) {
    this._baseUrl = baseUrl;
    this._headers = headers;
  }

  _checkRes(res) {
    console.log(res)
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    } else {
      return res.text().then((err) =>
        Promise.reject({
          status: res.status,
          message: JSON.parse(err).message,
        })
      );
    }
  }

  getBasetabel(enterprise, jwt) {
    return fetch(`${this._baseUrl}/tabels/base/${enterprise}`, {
      headers: {
        ...this._headers,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
      },
    }).then(this._checkRes);
  }
}

    const api = new Api({
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});
```

Так вот, как мне правильно скачать сам файл без записи на диск? Пытался сам разобраться, но понял, что ищу в не верном направлении.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Запись на диск где? На бэке?

Comment: @swad запись на диск должна быть только на стороне клиента, исключая бэк. Так как дисковое пространство на сервере где находится бэк огранично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// @ts-check
const express = require('express');
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (_req, res) => {
  const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
  workbook.title = 'abasj';

  const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet();
  worksheet.addRow([3, 'Harley', new Date()]);
  worksheet.addRow([4, 'Quinn', new Date()]);

  /* Ручная отправка заголовков  */
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Type',
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  );
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Disposition',
    `attachment; filename="${Date.now()}_My_Workbook.xlsx"`
  );

  /* Stream "записи" содержимого xlsx перенаправляется в ответ сервера express */
  workbook.xlsx.write(res)
    .then(() => res.end())
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('SERVER_ERROR');
    });
});


const port = 3001;
app.listen(
  port,
  () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
);
```